# MongoDB group and only show results whose count is greater than 1

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i would only like to retrieve results whose count is greater than 1 with this request, how can i do that ?

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$id"},count:{$sum:1}}]);
```

Thx in advance

Comment: Add $match stage with greater  than 0 comparison to keep matching documents. Something like `{$match:{count:{$gt:0}}}`

Comment: You can place match after group in the aggregation pipeline ?

Comment: Yes. Aggregation takes sequence of pipelines.

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: Could you give me the syntax ?...